# How to prevent empty cart after failed payment and how to manage the empty of cart according to condition

Tags: magento2

I want to prevent the behavior of the cart when a payment is failed and other things i want to manage empty of cart according to some condition: after palcing order i want to change to empty cart after two days for example if the order placed using checkmo method will be cancled or if i change the status of the order so how to proceed in this two problemes and thanks in advance